# Power analysis for RM-ANOVA

Tags: anova, statistical-power

I have tried running power analyses for both a 2x2 and 2x3 repeated measures-ANOVA (same alpha, power, etc). The results suggest I need more participants for the 2x2 design than the 2x3 design and i am struggling to conceptualize why? Is this the case, or am I likely calculating something wrong? If it is correct can someone please explain why?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your null hypothesis and the nature of your question.

But think of it as the quantity of information. If you have a 2x3 and a 2x2 with the same number of participants, you have more information in the 2x3. If you have more information, you have more power.